# I'm having trouble displaying divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I've done a good amount of research already and I haven't had much luck. In essence, I'm trying to format 4 images (2 x 2) in the right half of a section next to a large image. So far, I can only get two of the four images to display the way I'd like. I'm trying to get the other two to appear directly below the current two.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCQvL.png) is is what the section looks like before I add the second two

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiYUT.png) is what the section looks like after I add the second two.

This is the relevant HTML:

```
      <section>
    <div  style="font-style: italic;">

      <div style="float: right;">
        <div class="desc tooltip">
          <img src="image/alpaca.png" alt="alpaca image" class="species" title="Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)">
          <p>Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)</p>
          <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
        </div>
      
        <div class="desc tooltip">
          <img src="image/llama.png" alt="llama image" class="species" title="Llama (Lama glama)">
          <p>Llama (Lama glama)</p>
          <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="desc tooltip">
          <img src="image/vicuna.png" alt="vicuna image" class="species" title="Vicuna (Vicugna vicugna)">
          <p>Vicuna (Vicugna vicugna)</p>
          <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
        </div>
      
        <div class="desc tooltip ">
          <img src="image/guanaco.png" alt="guanaco image" class="species" title="Guanaco (Lama guanicoe)">
          <p>Guanaco (Lama guanicoe)</p>
          <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img class="tree_diagram" src="image/camelidae tree diagram.png" alt="camelidae tree diagram">

    </div>
  </section>
```

This is the relevant CSS:

```
.species {
   margin: 5px;
   width: 300px;
   box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px grey;
   border-radius: 20px;
   margin-right: 70px;
}
.tree_diagram {
   width: 45%;
   border-radius: 50px;
   border: 2px solid #101010;
   margin: 1em;
}
```

I've been at it for a while; I've tried changing the relative position, using flex-box, changing display types, media queries, the list goes on. Any help is appreciated & I tried keeping this as concise as possible so if there is any other information I should include then I will happily do so.

Comment: the javascript tag is wrong - CSS is the way to do it. floating may be fine, flexbox is probably better - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flexbox .. you might consider having the two rows of content in separate wrappers .. but the "right" (if there is such a thing) solution depends so heavily on other criteria your layout must meet. Are you doing any ResponsiveWebDesign(RWD) or just targeting one size?

Comment: Noted regarding the JS tag! I'm still trying to understand the "flex" display type so I appreciate the resources you provided. I attempted splitting the rows into separate wrappers once before but I'm not confident I did it correctly so I will certainly give it another go. To answer your question, yes, ideally I would like the website to be viewport-friendly once I'm done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the bootstrap grid system

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

If you not comfortable with bootstrap check out the semantic UI grid system it's easy to understand for beginners

https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

If you want CSS then try below CSS

```
display:inline-block
```

And change the height and width of the div

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make like this . I assure you that this will help you .

```
<div class="divTable" style="width: 100%; border: 0px solid #000;">
<div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow" colspan="2">
        <div width="100%">&nbsp;<img class="tree_diagram" src="image/camelidae tree diagram.png" alt="camelidae tree diagram"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"><div class="desc tooltip">
      <img src="image/alpaca.png" alt="alpaca image" class="species" title="Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)">
      <p>Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)</p>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
    </div></div>
        <div class="divTableCell">
    <div class="desc tooltip">
      <img src="image/alpaca.png" alt="alpaca image" class="species" title="Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)">
      <p>Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)</p>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"><div class="desc tooltip">
      <img src="image/alpaca.png" alt="alpaca image" class="species" title="Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)">
      <p>Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)</p>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
    </div></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"><div class="desc tooltip">
      <img src="image/alpaca.png" alt="alpaca image" class="species" title="Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)">
      <p>Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)</p>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
    </div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"><div class="desc tooltip">
      <img src="image/alpaca.png" alt="alpaca image" class="species" title="Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)">
      <p>Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)</p>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
    </div></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"><div class="desc tooltip">
      <img src="image/alpaca.png" alt="alpaca image" class="species" title="Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)">
      <p>Alpaca (Vicugna pacos)</p>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</span>
    </div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    .species {
   margin: 5px;
   width: 300px;
   box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px grey;
   border-radius: 20px;
   margin-right: 70px;
}
.tree_diagram {
   width: 45%;
   border-radius: 50px;
   border: 2px solid #101010;
   margin: 1em;
}
.divTable{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  
}
.divTableRow {
  text-align: center;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
  text-align: center;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    border: 0px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
  
}
.divTableFoot {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-footer-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added code snippet below please have a look in the below code.

```css
.leftDiv {
   width: 58%;
   border:1px solid red;
   float: left;
}
.rightDiv {
   width: 40%;
   border:1px solid red;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<section>
      <div class="leftDiv">
        Left div . you can put your left side content in this div and if you want to change its width then you can change it from the leftDiv css class
      </div>
      <div class="rightDiv">
         Right div. You can put your right side content in this div and if you want to change its widht then you can change it from the rightDiv css class  
      </div>
    </section>
```